# Passing a LazyColumn item to another function as a parameter

Tags: android

I have just taken up Android Studio and Kotlin, I am creating a collapsable menu which displays data from a JSON file.

I am trying to pass the contents of a LazyColumn Scope to another function but the compiler gives me error of unresolved reference.

```
@Composable
fun ItemIreater(content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit){

       items(content){
}

}
```

Comment: ```LazyListScope``` is not a Composable to just remove the ```@Composable``` annotation from the function and error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

To receive and place items of `LazyColumn`, use `LazyItemScope` and for multiple items, use `List` of `LazyItemScope` items as:

```
    @Composable
    fun ItemIreater(content: List<@Composable (LazyItemScope.() -> Unit)>){
        LazyColumn {
            items(content.size){
                content[it]()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Demo() {
        ItemIreater(content = listOf(
            { Text(text = "First item") },
            { Text(text = "Second item") }
        ))
    }
```

[image]

---

Alternately, you can pass items from the caller:

`ItemIreater` is just a simple composable function and has no relation with `LazyColumn`.
You need put the content in a `LazyColumn` composable

```
    @Composable
    fun ItemIreater(content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit){
        LazyColumn {
            content()
        }
    }
```

and pass the `LazyListScope` content as lambda:

```
    @Composable
    fun Demo() {
        ItemIreater(){
            item { Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {} }

            items(5){
                Text(text = "5 More items")
            }
        }
    }
```